# Render static content in new tab (express, ejs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

So, my express app runs fine, it has a mongodb backend and renders tables with data perfectly. Now, a table exported from my db looks like that:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3><a href="/products">Product List</a></h3>
    <h1>Product Detail</h1>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ORDERID</td>
                <td>=</td>
                <td>78978</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>WIDTH</td>
                <td>=</td>
                <td>1234</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<a href="......">TXT</a>
```

Now, when I hit the TXT-Hyperlink I'd like to have a new tab with a file called "78978.TXT", which is it ORDERID as a name. The content of the table has to be like this:

```
ORDERID = 78978
WIDTH = 1234
```

Somehow I don't see how this can be achieved. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use javascript to create file like `https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/`.

Or you can use third party like `https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver` to create txt file to download

Comment: Could you add a suggestion on how to get the content of the table in an efficient way?

Comment: you can also create a new route to download. See res.download(http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Comment: Thats working, but I still cannot "Download" stuff as there seems to be no route to that file so express does not allow me to download it and gives me a 404.

Comment: works now. I moved everything to the public folder, restarted server and it works. Thanks!